# How to totally fork a shell command that is using redirection

Tags: bash, scripting, nohup, fork

I've written quite a few shell scripts over the years (but I'm certainly not a sysadmin) and there's something that always caused me troubles: how can I fork a shell command immune to hangups in the background from a *Bash* script?

For example if I have this:

```
command_which_takes_time input > output
```

How can I "nohup" and fork this?

The following doesn't seem to do what I want:

```
nohup command_which_takes_time input > output &
```

What is the syntax I am looking for and what am I not understanding?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try creating subshell with `(...)` :

```
( command_which_takes_time input > output ) &
```

Example:

```
~$ ( (sleep 10; date) > /tmp/q ) &
[1] 19521
~$ cat /tmp/q # ENTER
~$ cat /tmp/q # ENTER
(...) #AFTER 10 seconds
~$ cat /tmp/q #ENTER
Wed Jan 11 01:35:55 CET 2012
[1]+  Done                    ( ( sleep 10; date ) > /tmp/q )
```

Answer (score 24):

You should try `setsid(1)`. Use it like you'd use `nohup`:

```
setsid command_which_takes_time input > output
```

This (as per the `setsid(2)` manpage), does a `fork(2)`, an `_exit(2)` of the parent process, then the child process calls `setsid(2)` to create a new process group (session).

You can't kill that by logging out, and it's not part of the Bash job control shebang. For all intents and purposes, it's a proper daemon.

Answer (score 5):

there is `disown` bash builtin command:

```
[1] 9180
root@ntb1:~# jobs
[1]+  Running                 sleep 120 &
root@ntb1:~# disown
root@ntb1:~# jobs
... no jobs, disowned
root@ntb1:~# ps aux | grep sleep | grep -v grep
root      9180  0.0  0.0   4224   284 pts/0    S    17:55   0:00 sleep 120
... but the sleep still runing
root@ntb1:~#
```

After **disown**, the job is disowned from your shell (so You can even logout) and it still remains running until finished.

See the 1st `jobs` command listed the `sleep` however the 2nd `jobs` after the disown did not. But using the `ps` we can see that the job is still running.

Answer (score 2):

Freebsd:

```
/usr/sbin/daemon -f <command> <command args>
```

Answer (score -3):

This will work (do not type any extra spaces):

```
command &>output.file
```

Comment: This seems to have nothing to do with the question, because it doesn't fork or achieve the equivalent of `nohup`.